# Queryable attribute is not compiling in mvc 4 web api when trying to mark for odata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using MVC 4 web api that comes with visual studio 2012.

As I've understand odata is not parsed automatically, but we need to add [Queryable] attribute to the action now.

So I added it:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<MyClass> GetMyClasses()
    {
       return ...;
    }
}
```

but I'm getting a compilation error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Queryable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is the odata still supported? and why Queryable is not recognized as an attribute as listed here.

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx), OData support has been moved to a separate [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData).

Answer (score 12):

It's in this Assembly (DLL) :

```
 System.Web.Http.OData.dll
```

This namespace :

```
System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute
```

In this nuget package :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData
```

When I installed the package however it didn't appear as a valid type. Even verifying that `System.Web.Http.OData.dll` was present and looking in Object Explorer I couldn't find it. Eventually I just restarted Visual Studio and everything was fine. I suspect some older version of this DLL may have been confusing it or something like that.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Be carefull which OData package you are installing