# Queryable attribute ambiguous Reference Error

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting Ambiguous Reference Error when i am adding [System.Web.Http.Queryable] attribute to api project.

```
The type 'System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute' exists in both 'c:\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.OData.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.dll'
```

but in my case I required  both dlls, how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstalled mvc4 and installed it, now it is working fine. I think the issue is because of versioning of below dll

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest WebApi and it will remove the old one that makes the collision

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -Version 5.3.1

Comment: Same advice as here, which also told me [Queryable] is deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28210658/1175496  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12554212/1175496

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes happen when you get old assemblies in .NET cache.
Try clearing contents of those folders:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: Do you have in your project references to both libraries mentioned in the error? If so you should have only one.

Comment: yes i have but I need classes and methods in both dll

Comment: Similar question was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527839/… You can try creating a different project referencing only one of the libraries. Then, in original project, you can reference the second library and your "wrapper" project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following...

```
using ODATA = System.Web.Http.OData;
using HTTP = System.Web.Http;
```

and then you can reference your type accordingly...

Comment: two refence of System.Web.Http.Queryable is there when referring  HTTP.Queryable